# Flowable: Jackson transformation Deployment of flowable, prompt CommandContextUtil. GetResourceEntityManager () is null

Tags: java, jackson, flowable

This is my call

```
public IPage<Deployment> deploymentPage(Query query, String key, String name, String tenantId) {
    DeploymentQuery deploymentQuery = repositoryService.createDeploymentQuery();
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(key)) {
        deploymentQuery.deploymentKeyLike(StringPool.PERCENT + key + StringPool.PERCENT);
    }
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(name)) {
        deploymentQuery.deploymentNameLike(StringPool.PERCENT + name + StringPool.PERCENT);
    }
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(tenantId)) {
        deploymentQuery.deploymentTenantId(tenantId);
    }
    IPage<Deployment> page = Condition.getPage(query);
    long count = deploymentQuery.count();
    List<Deployment> deployments = deploymentQuery.orderByTenantId().orderByDeploymentTime().desc().listPage((query.getCurrent() - 1) * query.getSize(), query.getSize());
    page.setRecords(deployments);
    page.setTotal(count);
    return page;
}
```

I use `JSON` to return `IPage\<Deployment\>`

Error:

> Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested
> exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was
> java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain:
> org.springblade.core.tool.api.R["data"]->com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.pagination.Page["records"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.flowable.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentEntityImpl["resources"])

After locating, it was found that `CommandContextUtil.getResourceEntityManager().findResourcesByDeploymentId(id);` line `CommandContextUtil.getResourceEntityManager()` is null

```
    @Override
    public Map<String, EngineResource> getResources() {
        if (resources == null && id != null) {
            List<ResourceEntity> resourcesList = CommandContextUtil.getResourceEntityManager().findResourcesByDeploymentId(id);
            resources = new HashMap<>();
            for (ResourceEntity resource : resourcesList) {
                resources.put(resource.getName(), resource);
            }
        }
        return resources;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-batch Entity Manager becomes null after init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406832/spring-batch-entity-manager-becomes-null-after-init)

Answer (score 1):

The public Java API classes from Flowable, such as `Deployment`, are not build to be returned directly over REST. If you want to return them, you'll need to create your own DTOs to achieve what you want to achieve.